# Android Instagram API

Tags: post, web, instagram, instagram-api

I want to get user data using Instagram API. To do this, use the link:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/myFriendsName/?access_token=myTokenHere&scope=public_content
```

When I use this link i get an error that "the page is not available".

---

But when I use the link like this everything works

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=myAccessToken
```

what am I doing wrong? what I need to do to get the data of other users?

Answer (score 0):

Hello you have that error because the URL is wrong, the correct URL is:

1. https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

You need {user-id},so if you don't have the user-id, you can search the user-id from the user-name using the following URL:

2. https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=**jack**&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

"jack" is your "FriendNAme" with this URL you can extract the user-id and use the first one.